# Image file size changes in express-fileupload

Tags: javascript, react-native, express, express-fileupload

In a project I'm working on this I found this issue. For example the uploading size of an image is 192kb But after it uploads it's like 582kb. I'm using React Native and Express JS.

Using `express-fileupload` library to handle upload files in expressjs.

Below is the route for the file upload.

```
router.post(
  "/event",
  fileUpload({
    safeFileNames: true,
    preserveExtension: true,
  }),
  CreateEvent
);
```

This is the function where I move my image to a folder,

```
let logo = null;

  if (req.files?.logo) {
    let file = req.files?.logo;

    if (Array.isArray(file)) {
      file = file[0];
    }
    console.log(file?.name);
    console.log(file?.size);
    logo = `logo_${req.body.name + Date.now() + "." + file?.name.split(".")[1]}`;

    const imagePath = path.join(__dirname, "../../uploads", "venue_banners", logo);
    file?.mv(imagePath, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json(err);
      }
    });
  }
```

Also: I'm using form data to upload images in React Native.